# ChartJS hybrid chart not splitting datasets according to labels

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, boxplot

I am trying to plot some hybrid charts using chartjs, with the [boxplot plugin](https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-chart-boxplot).  The docs there have some instructions on doing [hybrid charts](https://www.sgratzl.com/chartjs-chart-boxplot/examples/hybrid.html), which is similar to ChartJS's docs on [mixed chart types](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html).  Here is how I am trying to render my chart:

```
import { BoxPlotChart } from "@sgratzl/chartjs-chart-boxplot";

const chart = new BoxPlotChart(ctx, {
  data: {
    labels: ["io_current", "usage_bytes"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "io_current",
        type: "boxplot",
        borderColor: "green",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(128, 222, 234, 0.5)",
        outlierBackgroundColor: "rgb(128, 222, 234, 0.5)",
        data: [
          {
            min: 64,
            max: 458,
            median: 252,
            q1: 86,
            q3: 436,
            outliers: [43, 480],
            whiskerMin: 64,
            whiskerMax: 458,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: "io_current",
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(227, 185, 0)",
        data: [[152, 370]],
      },
      {
        label: "usage_bytes",
        type: "boxplot",
        borderColor: "green",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(128, 222, 234, 0.5)",
        outlierBackgroundColor: "rgb(128, 222, 234, 0.5)",
        data: [
          {
            min: 50,
            max: 414,
            median: 218,
            q1: 70,
            q3: 394,
            outliers: [30, 435],
            whiskerMin: 50,
            whiskerMax: 414,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: "usage_bytes",
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(227, 185, 0)",
        data: [[131, 333]],
      },
    ],
  };
});
```

As you see, there are 2 "columns" of data I want to plot, labeled `io_current` and `usage_bytes`.  I specify that in the `labels` array.  In `datasets`, there are 4 entries - a box plot for each label, and a bar chart fo each label.  When I render this, I see that all charts are rendered in the first label:

[image]

But my goal is that the right charts should be rendered in the right box, above the `usage_bytes` label.  What am I doing wrong in the way I'm organizing my `data` such that all plots are being rendered above the first label?

Comment: I would like to have a runnable version of your code to explore the details of the chart (e.g., like a codesandbox or stackblitz), but from a superficial look at the code I see this: for each dataset, the inner `data` array: the first item in that array goes under the first label (`io_current`) and the the second item in that array goes under the second label (`usage_bytes`), and so on for more labels. But each of these arrays in your code only have one item, which explains why you're having nothing under the second label.

Comment: @kikon this was it.  I reworked my data a bit to fit that structure.  Friday was a long day 